# Error executing "npm run test" with cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm learning cypress, but I came across this error.

When running npm run test the cypress window open for a while, but a couple seconds later it close, then this error appears:

[image: Error]

I already installed the lastest cypress version and it didn't work.

Comment: What script do you run?

Comment: I have tried only run the "install cypress --save -include=dev" files

Comment: Can you add your package.json?

Comment: Sure. I put it in the description

Comment: Thanks, btw stack overflow does not allow images of code, just put your code inside a code block(example: ``` code ```).
Also, please attempt what I suggested and replay if that worked :)

Comment: I see "electron" in the error stack - does it occur with the chrome browser as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem was admin permission. When the blank window opened for a while, I clicked on the windows and authorized it again as adm. It worked!

I had authorized as adm before, but I don't know why it was happening.

Thanks you all guys for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `cypress cache clear` and then `npm install cypress --save-dev` again.

then try running it with `./node_modules/.bin/cypress open`.

Comment: Nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these steps:

1. Delete `node_modules` folder
2. Run `npm install -D cypress`
3. Run `npx cypress open`

Comment: Didn't work too